# Random forests with MATLAB - "Unable to create unique default labels using only 5 significant digits."

Tags: matlab, random-forest

I'm trying to use the random forest algorithm in MATLAB for prediction. However, I'm having issues getting it to run correctly. Function signature is as follows.

```
B = TreeBagger(NTrees,X,Y)
```

If I understand this correctly, NTrees is the number of trees to put grow, X is the feature matrix, where a row corresponds to an observation and a coloumn to one feature,  and Y the corresponding labels to X.

When using it to perform classification, I set the option 'Method' to 'classification'. However, I get the following error message:

> Unable to create unique default labels using only 5
>   significant digits.  Use the LABELS input argument.

The documentation here http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.html does not specify anything about a LABELS command. Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: From that documentation you showed, it looks like Y is an array of true class labels for classification or numeric function values for regression.  I think the problem is Y.  What does Y contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what Y is in your specific case, I think it is the source of your error.  The documentation says that Y is an array of true class labels...  True class labels can be a numeric vector, character matrix, vector cell array of strings or categorical vector.

A categorical vector throws the following error in matlab (found this [here](http://www.mbfys.ru.nl/~robvdw/CNP04/LAB_ASSIGMENTS/LAB05_CN05/MATLAB2007b/stats/@categorical/categorical.m)):

```
function b = categorical(a,labels,levels,edges)
...
b.labels = labels;
if isnumeric(levels)
    b.labels = cellstr(num2str(levels,'%0.5g'))';
    if length(unique(b.labels)) < length(b.labels)
        error('stats:categorical:categorical:CantInferNumericLabels', ...
                ['Unable to create default labels using only 5 significant ' ...
                 'digits.\nUse the LABELS input argument.']);
    end
 ...
end
```

So it looks to me like in your categorical vector Y, matlab can't infer the numeric labels, because perhaps some of them have more than 5 significant digits.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. Vector Y contained classes whose label had values larger than what can be represented with 5 digits. Mapping those to a lower range fixed the issue.